# Algorithm to identify the next higher figure which can be divided by a power of 10

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

I'm calculating a number which should be the stepsize of an axis on a barchart.

The calculated number is the smallest possible one (taking the available pixels etc into account).

Now I want to round these number up to the next power of 10.

This is how I calculate the smallest possible stepsize:

```
var maxNumberOfBars = Math.DivRem(this.Pixel, 8, out remainder); //8 is the min width of a bar
var minRange = (range.End - range.Start) / maxNumberOfBars;`
```

I'll give some examples for a better understanding:
Calculated number: 6 - number I want: 10

Calculated number: 55 - number I want: 100

Calculated number: 355 - number I want: 1000

Calculated number: 755 - number I want: 1000

Calculated number: 5755 - number I want: 10000

So I need some calculation which fits for all of these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Math.Pow(10,(int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number)));
```

Match your example

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with `Math.Log`:

```
int val = 55;
var power = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(val));
int calcNum = (int)Math.Pow(10, power);

// outputs 100
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OHL70920)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
int result = (int)Math.Pow(10,Math.Round(Math.Log(n,10) - Math.Log(5.5,10) + 0.5));
```

Taken from:

> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=816175

Bichromat's solution

Answer (score 1):

You can take the base 10 log and round it up to the next higher digit and do a Math.Pow consequently.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> number = new List<int> { 5, 55, 555, 5555, 55555 };
    number.Select(ReturnLog10Exponent).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

static int ReturnLog10Exponent(int Number)
{
    double base10Log = Math.Round((Math.Log(Number) / Math.Log(10)), 0);
    return (int)Math.Pow(10, base10Log);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```